# VSC icons for sass are not recognized

Tags: sass

I,m having a hard time with Sass instalation.
I already have it installed by npm:**

[image]

But looks like the files .sass and .scss are not recognized by VSC**

[image]

Do I have to run or install sometching else?**
Is Sass extension in VSC have to be installed?

Comment: what do you mean by not recognized?

Comment: Writing a code in.sass file doesn't it format in sass or css way. It simply doesnt work

Comment: Did you install an extension for it?

Comment: Just a few minutes ago i Instaled this: Sass (.sass only) for VSC and it seems to work.
But as i look through sass instalation tutorial there was no mention that this kind of extension is needed.